# Kendo UI - Change Tooltip color?

Tags: css, kendo-ui

i need to change the default Kendo UI Tooltip color.
I've insert this code in my .css file:

```
.k-tooltip {
background: black !important;
border-color: black !important;    
}
```

But it doesn't change tip color that remains green.

[image]

Is possible to change that with css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your css file:

```
.k-callout-s {
     border-top-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this checkout..
HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
   title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on bottom"
   class="red-tooltip">color tooltip</a>
```

css:

```
.tooltip-arrow,
.red-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: #f00;}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckxSs/16/)

here is one more link hope it will help
[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/vORZOb)